# How To: Store type safe Key/Value Pairs in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need to store type safe entity key/value pairs in EF Core.

**Key Value Types**

```
// KeyValuePair<string,bool>
// KeyValuePair<string,int>
// KeyValuePair<string,string>
// KeyValuePair<string,float>
// KeyValuePair<string,DateTime>
```

**Entity**

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,T>> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

**Elsewhere**

```
{
    …
    dbContext.MyEntity.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,bool>("Active", true);
    dbContext.MyEntity.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Customer", "Microsoft");
    dbContext.MyEntity.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Street", "1 Microsoft Way");
    dbContext.MyEntity.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,float>("Rating",5.0);
}
```

How can this be accomplished in EF Core?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late for an answer, but I had the same problem trying to persist keyvalue pairs.
The only way I found was to strong type them, since EF has no clue on how to persist the KeyValue entity.

Here's my model:

```
public class Payment
{
    //-- Properties
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PaymentField> PaymentFields { get; set; } = new List<PaymentField>();        
}

public class PaymentField
{
    //-- Properties
    [Key]
    public int PaymentFieldId { get; set; }

    // References master table
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PaymentFieldItem> PaymentFieldItems { get; set; } = new List<PaymentFieldItem>();
}

public class PaymentFieldItem
{
    public int PaymentFieldItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int PaymentFieldId { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentField PaymentField { get; set; }
}
```

Hope you can adjust to your own needs.